# If I only change the syntax highlighting in a post, is that proper editing?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

So, I was editing a question due to it's syntax highlighting, and as most of you know, you can direct StackOverflow to change the syntax highlighting of a code block with the HTML comment:

```
<!-- language: (the language here) -->
```

But I noticed two things about this:

1. <strike>Adding comments aren't shown in edit review pages, as you can see from [my recent edit here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8228099)</strike> You can see HTML comments by clicking the "Markdown" option in the review edits screen.
2. This doesn't benefit the question too much in my eyes.  Just changes the way it appears.

So, my question is, would only changing the syntax highlighting of code-blocks in a question be considered a proper edit / a good edit?

Comment: From what I see, that didn't improve the post at all. However, there are some grammar issues that, if fixed, would have been fine along with your edit.

Comment: @codeMagic, look at #1, they're aren't visible in the review

Comment: I don't think I completely understand. What isn't visible? The first in the review is the OP, not the 1st edit

Comment: @codeMagic, my mistake, I should clarify more.  In order to change the syntax highlighting of a code-block you use the HTML comment (as you see in this post).  But in the review stage you can't see HTML comments.

Comment: Right, but you do see it if you click the "side-by-side markdown" button in the review. Or am I still confused and should get some sleep? Also, if you think *"This doesn't benefit the question too much"* then why did you suggest it?

Comment: Ohhh, I guess I haven't noticed that.

Comment: :) My second question still stands

Comment: I was wondering if other people think it benefit the post or not.  I guess multiple opinions is more powerful than one?

Comment: Ah, ok. Was just trying to get to the root of the question. But I answered that in my first comment.

Answer (score 26):

As per usual, if there's nothing else wrong with the question, an edit that fixes syntax highlighting is fine.

However, you should strive to fix all of the issues in a given post with edits, so if there *is* anything else wrong, you should remedy it as well.

In this particular case, you could have fixed some minor grammar flaws to improve the readability and clarity of the question, but I can see why you might find those changes unnecessary for this question (I went ahead and made them already).

Whether a reviewer can tell that something has changed is irrelevant here, as it's the duty of the reviewer to examine different views in the suggested edits queue to determine what changes have been made to a post. If necessary, make it clear in your edit summary (as you did).

Answer (score 7):

If the net effect of your edit is a positive one for the post, by all means, make the edit. If you are worried about others not understanding your edit, leave an edit comment.

Comment: " net effect", as long as you feel you've fixed *everything* that you could

Comment: There is no such requirement. Just make a positive edit.

Comment: Maybe no requirement but that's how it should be done. So if I make a single change of "i" to "I", that is enough, even if there are many more obvious improvements to be made?

Comment: No, that is how you desire it. There is a difference between 'it would be nice' and 'ought to'.

Comment: So proper grammar and spelling is a "desire" and not an "ought to"? Incorrect. We strive for proper grammar, spelling, formatting, and clarity here. What is an "ought to" for you? Formatting? What if I fix one small formatting line but not many other obvious formatting fixes? That's ok?

Comment: Stop trying to force other people to do work that you desire to do. Some people want to give 10%, others want to give 100%. All are valuable.

Comment: I'm not trying to force anyone to do anything. I'm simply suggesting what's best for the site. Stop trying to get people to be less than their best. And you still didn't answer the questions.

Comment: You are trying to force people. You are using 'ought to'.

“Socialism, like the ancient ideas from which it springs, confuses the distinction between government and society. As a result of this, every time we object to a thing being done by government, the socialists conclude that we object to its being done at all. We disapprove of state education. Then the socialists say that we are opposed to any education. We object to a state religion.

Comment: Then the socialists say that we want no religion at all. We object to a state-enforced equality. Then they say that we are against equality. And so on, and so on. It is as if the socialists were to accuse us of not wanting persons to eat because we do not want the state to raise grain.”


― Frédéric Bastiat, The Law

Comment: I'm not trying to force anyone. I'm simply trying to encourage best practices. Developers understand what that means

Comment: edits may bump question so that others have to see it. If you can't give 100%; don't edit: you'll be wasting somebody else's time.

Comment: You are again describing a problem with the system, not the edit.

Comment: I'm with GEOCHET on this one, but the site consensus seems to be "do everything you can, or do nothing". In response, I do a lot less edits to fix things than I could, because the implication is that if I cannot spare 15 minutes to fully fix all of a post's typos and grammar problems, then I should not bother.

Comment: maybe it is more about the edits being done by users under 2k rep. If it has to be reviewed by multiple other people and it is just i to I, and there is something else that can be fixed in the post, I wouldn't be surprised by a reject and edit

Comment: @Neil: And that is a damn shame.

Comment: "maybe it is more about the edits being done by users under 2k rep. " - Fix the system then.